# Citation with only the author name

Tags: biblatex

I have the following paragraph;

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
Open Multilingual WordNet~\cite{bond_survey_2012} set out to discover the effect of choosing the correct license for wordnets.
\ldots
Thankfully, \textcite{bond_survey_2012} have standardized the wordnets and are currently hosting them from a single source.
\end{document}
```

Assuming bond_survey_2012 exists on my .bib file;

```
@article{bond_survey_2012,
  title = {A {{Survey}} of {{WordNets}} and Their {{Licenses}}},
  abstract = {This paper surveys currently avail-able wordnets. We measure the ef-fect that license choice has on their us-age, measured by the number of cita-tions. Finally, we discuss methods to make wordnets more generally accessi-ble, starting with a shared online server for freely distributable wordnets.},
  date = {2012-01-01},
  author = {Bond, Francis and Paik, Kyonghee},
}
```

I would like to have an output similar to below;

> Open Multilingual WordNet [1] set out to discover the effect of
>   choosing the correct license for wordnets.   ...   Thankfully, **Bond &
>   Paik** have standardized the wordnets and are currently hosting them
>   from a single source.

Note that [1] is not repeated.

Edit: Embarrassingly found the answer under biblatex documentation, the question did not appear on search engines which is why I asked the question in the first place, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From the biblatex [documentation](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf);

> ```
> \citeauthor[〈prenote〉][〈postnote〉]{〈key〉}
> \citeauthor*[〈prenote〉][〈postnote〉]{〈key〉}
> \Citeauthor[〈prenote〉][〈postnote〉]{〈key〉}
> \Citeauthor*[〈prenote〉][〈postnote〉]{〈key〉}
> ```
>
> These commands print the authors.
>   Strictly speaking, it prints thelabelnamelist, which may be theauthor, theeditor, or thetranslator.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
Open Multilingual WordNet~\cite{bond_survey_2012} set out to discover the effect of choosing the correct license for wordnets.
\ldots
Thankfully, \citeauthor{bond_survey_2012} have standardized the wordnets and are currently hosting them from a single source.
\end{document}
```

Gives the intended result.